# Git pull creating duplicate files with (conflict_on_<date>) in name

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict, github-desktop

Occasionally when I run `git pull`, certain files appear with `(conflict_on_<date>)` at the end of the file. I don't know what is causing this, and searching on both Google and Stack has offered no results. The files don't always have changes, and some of the duplicate files with `conflict_on` in the name are git-ignored files.

> Process:
>
> 1. Have an `environment.ts` file (gitignored, with local changes)
> 2. Run git pull
> 3. A file is created in the same directory as `environment.ts`, named `environment (conflict_on_12-16-21).ts`

Running this on Mac OS Monterey on a M1 pro chip mac. Sometimes use git desktop, sometimes use git command line. Git version 2.30.1

What is causing this and how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: Are you using a cloud-synced directory as your working tree? (e.g., iCloud or google drive) If so, that's the problem; don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Is this in Jetbrains IDE? Sounds like [a file cache conflict](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-cache-conflict.html)

> If an external process changes a file that was opened and unsaved in PhpStorm, it results in two conflicting versions of the file

Comment: This is happening in vscode, though now that you mention it, this file in particular does get modified by another process..hmmm